# If a probability distribution doesn't hold the regularity condition, then how can we find the variance of maximum likelihood estimator of parameter?

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics, statistical-significance, maximum-likelihood, inference

I am working with a distribution in which the support value of x depends upon the parameter and when I obtaining the Fisher Information of the MLE, it exists and giving some constant value. So, in order to find the asymptotic variance of the parameter, can I take the inverse of the Fisher Information matrix even they violets the C.R. Regularity condition?